# How to create a column with rows in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I want to create a table that withholds an array of values inside one column in table.

Example in JSON form:

```
 "trainNumber": 1,
 "departureDate": "2020-01-26",
 "operatorUICCode": 10,
 "operatorShortCode": "vr",
 "trainType": "IC",
 "trainCategory": "Long-distance",
 "commuterLineID": "",
 "runningCurrently": false,
 "cancelled": false,
 "version": 266667265768,
 "timetableType": "REGULAR",
 "timetableAcceptanceDate": "2019-11-08T10:34:22.000Z",
 "timeTableRows": [
   {
     "type": "DEPARTURE",
     "scheduledTime": "2020-01-26T04:57:00.000Z",
     "causes": []
   },
   {
     "type": "ARRIVAL",
     "scheduledTime": "2020-01-26T05:02:00.000Z",
     "causes": []
   },
   {
     "type": "DEPARTURE",
     "scheduledTime": "2020-01-26T05:03:00.000Z",
     "causes": []
   },
   {
     "type": "ARRIVAL",
     "causes": []
   },
   {
     "type": "DEPARTURE",
     "cancelled": false,
     "scheduledTime": "2020-01-26T05:05:00.000Z",
     "causes": []
   },
```

As show in example "timeTableRows".

How do I create this?

Comment: There is an [array data type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/arrays.html) in Postgres, but you shouldn't really store non-atomic values in columns of a relational database.

Comment: Do you mean; how to insert a json text in a table?

Comment: @mustaccio Is there a reason for that? I am creating a reservation calendar where I need to enter reserved hours into db. I cant think of another way to do this since it doesn't sound reasonable to create 24 different columns for every hour.

Comment: @McNets no. Creating a db for reservation calendar.

Comment: If you're unsure how to model your view of the universe (or its little corner), that would be a different question, and you'll need to describe your universe in greater detail. You should not have non-atomic attributes (which in your case look like proper entities in their own right) in a relational model.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a json array column (json[]), but it depends on your access patterns  what the best column type would be.

Example:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName
ADD COLUMN timeTableRows json[];
```

And then:

```
INSERT INTO tableName 
(
    timeTableRows
) 
VALUES
( array['{
   "type": "DEPARTURE",
   "scheduledTime": "2020-01-26T04:57:00.000Z",
   "causes": []
 }',
 '{
   "type": "ARRIVAL",
   "scheduledTime": "2020-01-26T05:02:00.000Z",
   "causes": []
 }']::json[])
```